# NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setDisallowDocTypeDeclaration(boolean)'

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

`I am currently writing a program to convert Excel files into XML files, but I have encountered some errors from IDEA that prompt me:
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setDisallowDocTypeDeclaration(boolean)'

---

I had tried many methods but no use

### Here are my codes:

```
package com.ericsson.function.util;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;

public class EasytestlinkUtil {

    private static String excelPath = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\hahaha.xlsx";
    private static String sheetName = "test";
    private static String xmlPath = ".";

    public void processToXml(String excelPath, String sheetName, String xmlPath) {
        try {
            // Load the Excel file
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

            // Create the root element for the XML
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("testcases");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // Process each row in the Excel sheet starting from row 4
            for (int rowNum = 4; rowNum <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                String tcId = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                String tcSummary = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                String tcPrecondition = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                String tcPriority = row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
                String tcAutomationAbleStr = row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
                String tcAction = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
                String tcException = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();

                // Create the testcase element
                Element testcase = doc.createElement("testcase");
                rootElement.appendChild(testcase);

                // Create and append elements for testcase details
                createAndAppendElement(doc, testcase, "internalid", tcId.replace("TC", "").replace(".", ""));
                createAndAppendElement(doc, testcase, "name", tcSummary.substring(0, Math.min(100, tcSummary.length())));
                createAndAppendElement(doc, testcase, "summary", tcSummary);
                createAndAppendElement(doc, testcase, "preconditions", tcPrecondition.replace('\n', '\u2028'));

                // Create steps element
                Element steps = doc.createElement("steps");
                testcase.appendChild(steps);

                // Create step element
                Element step = doc.createElement("step");
                steps.appendChild(step);

                createAndAppendElement(doc, step, "step_number", "1");
                createAndAppendElement(doc, step, "actions", tcAction);
                createAndAppendElement(doc, step, "expectedresults", tcException);
                createAndAppendElement(doc, step, "importance", getImportanceValue(tcPriority));
                createAndAppendElement(doc, step, "execution_type", "Yes".equals(tcAutomationAbleStr) ? "2" : "1");
            }

            // Create a pretty-formatted XML string
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(xmlPath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("The XML file is successfully created");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void createAndAppendElement(Document doc, Element parentElement, String elementName, String elementValue) {
        Element element = doc.createElement(elementName);
        element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(elementValue));
        parentElement.appendChild(element);
    }

    private String getImportanceValue(String priority) {
        if ("High".equals(priority)) {
            return "3";
        } else if ("Medium".equals(priority)) {
            return "2";
        } else {
            return "1";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EasytestlinkUtil converter = new EasytestlinkUtil();
        converter.processToXml(excelPath, sheetName, xmlPath);
    }
}
```

Here are my Modules and Libraries:

poi 4.0.1
xml beans 5.1.1
In my previous attempts, an error occurred that DocumntFactory not found in xmlbeans, I suspect there is a conflict between my dependencies.So I streamlined the dependencies of my project structure in IDEA, but the following issues arose: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setDisallowDocTypeDeclaration(boolean)'

I hope anyone can help me to find this method :
setDisallowDocTypeDeclaration

In fact,I have already written this code in Python and it can run normally, I am a green hand in java, and I think apache POI and xmlbeans are so unfriendly to me...

And here are my python source code, I hope it can help you to help me locate problem:

```
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog, Button, Entry, Label, Tk

import openpyxl
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
from xml.dom import minidom


def process_excel_to_xml(excel_file_path, sheet_name, output_xml_path):
    try:
        # Load the Excel file
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
        sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "File not found. Please choose a valid Excel file.")
        return
    except KeyError:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Sheet '{sheet_name}' not found in the Excel file.")
        return

    # Load the Excel file
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]

    # Create the root element for the XML
    root = Element("testcases")

    # Process each row in the Excel sheet starting from row 4
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=4, values_only=True):
        # Extract the values from the Excel columns
        tc_id = row[1]
        tc_summary = row[2]
        tc_preconditions = row[3]
        tc_priority = row[9]
        tc_automationable = row[10]
        tc_action = row[4]
        tc_exception = row[5]

        # Skip the row if TC ID is empty
        if not tc_id:
            continue

        # Create the testcase element
        testcase = SubElement(root, "testcase")
        testcase.set("internalid", tc_id.replace("TC", "").replace(".", ""))
        testcase.set("name", tc_summary.strip()[:100] if tc_summary else "")

        # Create the summary element
        summary = SubElement(testcase, "summary")
        summary.text = "<p>{}</p>".format(tc_summary[:100]) if tc_summary else ""

        # Create the preconditions element
        preconditions = SubElement(testcase, "preconditions")
        preconditions.text = "<p>{}</p>".format(tc_preconditions.replace('\n', '<br/>')) if tc_preconditions else ""

        steps = SubElement(testcase, "steps")

        # Combine TC Action (E column) and TC Exception (F column) into one string with line breaks
        combined_actions = "\n".join("<p>{}</p>".format(action.strip()) for action in str(tc_action).split('\n') if action.strip())
        combined_exceptions = "\n".join("<p>{}</p>".format(exception.strip()) for exception in str(tc_exception).split('\n') if exception.strip())

        # Create the step element
        step = SubElement(steps, "step")
        step_number = SubElement(step, "step_number")
        step_number.text = "<![CDATA[1]]>"

        # Create the actions element
        actions = SubElement(step, "actions")
        actions.text = combined_actions

        # Create the expectedresults element
        expectedresults = SubElement(step, "expectedresults")
        expectedresults.text = combined_exceptions

        # Create the importance element
        importance = SubElement(testcase, "importance")
        if tc_priority == "High":
            importance.text = "<![CDATA[3]]>"
        elif tc_priority == "Medium":
            importance.text = "<![CDATA[2]]>"
        else:
            importance.text = "<![CDATA[1]]>"

        # Create the execution_type element
        execution_type = SubElement(testcase, "execution_type")
        if tc_automationable == "Yes":
            execution_type.text = "<![CDATA[2]]>"
        elif tc_automationable == "No":
            execution_type.text = "<![CDATA[1]]>"

    # Create a pretty-formatted XML string
    xml_string = minidom.parseString(tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="    ", newl="\n", encoding="utf-8").decode()

    # Remove empty lines caused by pretty-printing
    xml_lines = xml_string.split("\n")
    xml_lines = [line for line in xml_lines if line.strip()]
    xml_string = "\n".join(xml_lines)

    # Write the XML string to a file with UTF-8 encoding
    with open(output_xml_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as xml_file:
        xml_file.write(xml_string)

    messagebox.showinfo("Info", "The XML file is successfully created")


def choose_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
    if file_path:
        entry_file_path.delete(0, "end")
        entry_file_path.insert(0, file_path)


def choose_output_folder():
    output_folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if output_folder:
        entry_output_folder.delete(0, "end")
        entry_output_folder.insert(0, output_folder)


def generate_xml():
    excel_file_path = entry_file_path.get()
    sheet_name = entry_sheet_name.get()
    output_folder = entry_output_folder.get()

    if not excel_file_path or not sheet_name or not output_folder:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please enter the file path, sheet name, and choose the output folder.")
        return

    output_xml_path = f"{output_folder}/output.xml"
    process_excel_to_xml(excel_file_path, sheet_name, output_xml_path)


# Create the main application window
root = Tk()
root.title("Easy Testlink XML generator")

# Create widgets
label_file_path = Label(root, text="Excel File:")
entry_file_path = Entry(root, width=40)
button_browse = Button(root, text="Browse", command=choose_file)

label_sheet_name = Label(root, text="Sheet Name:")
entry_sheet_name = Entry(root, width=40)

label_output_folder = Label(root, text="Output Folder:")
entry_output_folder = Entry(root, width=40)
button_browse_output = Button(root, text="Browse", command=choose_output_folder)

button_generate = Button(root, text="Generate XML", command=generate_xml)

# Grid layout
label_file_path.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_file_path.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
button_browse.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

label_sheet_name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_sheet_name.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

label_output_folder.gr`your text`id(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_output_folder.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
button_browse_output.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

button_generate.grid(row=3, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=10)

# Create a prompt area
prompt_label = Label(root, text="Please use a standard TA template Excel file!!!", fg="red")
prompt_label.config(font=("Arial", 14, "italic"))
prompt_label.grid(row=4, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=10)
# Pack the label to display it on the window


root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: This error generally means that you have the wrong version of a dependency on your classpath.

Comment: What dependency management system used? Using maven only `<dependency<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId><version>5.2.3</version></dependency>` is needed. That should pull all other dependencies inclusive the correct version of `xmlbeans`.

Answer (score 0):

The POI version is to low, try 5.1.0+

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).